# Postgres: Rewrite boolean datatype to numeric

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion, boolean

I have a database with a lot of tables which contain many columns of type boolean. But my software doesn't support boolean as a datatype. Their support team told me that I should use numeric(1,0) instead of boolean, so I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar TYPE numeric(1,0) USING bar::numeric(1,0)
```

I get an error: can't convert boolean into type numeric.
What can I do to replace the boolean columns with a numeric alternative and preserve the boolean behaviour? Can this numeric(1,0) thing even work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need an extra step - cast to int first:

```
t=# select true::int::numeric(1,0);
 numeric 
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

so in your case it would be:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar TYPE numeric(1,0) USING bar::int::numeric(1,0)
```

but frankly saying I believe just converting to int is already enough.

Comment: no, `t` is boolean or text. in your case obviously it is boolean. `int` stands for integer and should show `1` or `0`...